# How to write a schematron to ensure list-items are alphanumeric?

Tags: list, alphanumeric, schematron

Is it possible to use schematron to ensure that the list items are in alphanumeric order?

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>d</li>
    <li>g</li>
</ul>
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can use something like this example rule that reports all `<li>` elements whose value is lower than (`lt`) their previous `<li>` sibling value.

```
<sch:rule context="li">
    <sch:report test=". lt preceding-sibling::li[1]">
        This li value is lower than his previous li sibling value.
    </sch:report>
</sch:rule>
```